# Fast screenshot ios

Tags: ios, performance, screenshot, blur, low-level

In my project I have to make a screenshot of the screen and apply blur to create the effect of frosted glass. Content can be moved under the glass and blured picture changed.

I'v used Accelerate.framework to speedup blurring, also i,v used OpenGL to draw CIImage directly to GLView.

Now I'm looking for a way to optimize getting screenshot of the screen.
I use this method to get screenshot of some area at the bottom of the screen:

```
 CGSize size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

    // get screenshot of self.view
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, size.width, size.height, 8, 0, colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationNone);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ctx, NO);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, NO);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, someView.frame.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);

    //add mask
    CGImageRef maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"].CGImage;
    CGContextClipToMask(ctx, rect, maskImage);

    [someView.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    //get screenshot image
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
```

It works fine and fast if self.view has 1-2 subviews, but if there are several subviews (or it is tableview), then everything starts to slow down.

So i try to find a fast way to get pixels from some rect on screen. Maybe using a low-level API.

Comment: Is your main concern the speed of the actions listed above - or minimizing any impact to the user experience by not blocking the main thread?

Comment: The main goal is achieved responsive user interface while maintaining the designer's ideas. Now when the user scrolls the table view on the iPhone 4 number of frames per second is 20. I aspire to the 60 FPS. I reached these results using scrolling view, with one photo inside, but as soon as I use a table view or scroll view with multiple images, superimposed on each other - performance slowed down to 20 FPS.

Comment: Have you ensured that your tableview is reusing cells?

Answer (score 0):

if just perform some animations , try this way , called `-snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` or `-resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets:` method  which are UIView provided , these method return UIView object without rendering into a bitmap image , so it is a more efficient .